Manhwa and novel in which the female lead is forced to consummate her marriage with the male lead while being watched
The female lead (FL) comes back in time, because she dies while she was in prison and her (evil) sister gives her poison as a sign of help, but is actually for her to die, and she (the female lead) takes it because she doesn't want to suffer in prison. (I might be confusing this one, so I'm not 100% sure that actually happens.)
The female lead was married to the male lead (ML) and I think they were kind of emperor and empress.
But the manhwa starts the story not since the regression but since the wedding, where the FL and ML were forced to spent the night together and the other royals watched them (there was a veil around the bed) including the mom of the ML, to see if they consummated their marriage.
I don't remember much of it, but the male lead had black hair and the female lead tried to escape multiple times but the male lead chased after her; maybe a soldier helped her one time.
Manhwa with a similar concept but NOT THE ONE I'm talking about:

Revolutionary Princess Eve

I Don't Want to Be Loved

I Don't Love You Anymore

Golden Time

The Princess Imprints A Traitor

The World Without My Sister Who Everyone Loved

To Those Who Long for My Destruction

My Beloved Oppressor


I also remember a TikTok I saw where the FL was running away from the male lead and he was chasing after her with a horse, and she had like a hood to cover herself while trying to escape.
The important scene is the one where they consummate their marriage with people where watching them, but it's not that explicit, because there was a veil around the bed, but still. That is the only thing I remember that I'm sure about, and the kind of ugly art.
The manhwa starts, I think, with the scene I mentioned before, where the ML forces himself on FL because they have to consummate their marriage and there is like a veil around the bed and people watching, including the ML's mom, to see if they consummate the marriage.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?

Hi, thank you i read this a while ago, is a Manhwa and also a novel, is not a new Manhwa btw, kind of old but not that much
